# How do I include image in BootstrapVue carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add an image to the **img-src=""** attribute of b-carousel in BoostrapVue. The image is currently saved in the asset folder.

```html
  <b-carousel-slide img-src="../assets/life.jpg">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      </b-carousel-slide>
```

[image]

I have added
Find below images of the result:
[image]

I am certain the images are correctly saved in the right location: 
[image]

Comment: Check the network tab. It's probably not trying to load the image from where you think it is.

Comment: Are you positive that `../assets/life.jpg` is the correct file location for the image?

Comment: @BLAKE I am certain that it is the correct file location. I have included an image to show the actual file structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using a loader with webpack (i.e. vue-loader, url-loader, etc), you need to ensure that the loader knows that `img-src` accepts a URL.

See the docs on information on how to tell the loaders to handle URL props on custom components: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/images (specifically Vue Loader `transformAssetUrls`)

Comment: How do I modify this? Couldnt find vue.config.js in my project file

Comment: It might be in your webpack.config.js file or if using Nuxt.js in your nuxt.config.js.file. https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#asset-url-handling