# Image is not displaying in Vue-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I can't understand why this `img-src` is not working in my vue template. May be it's my simple mistake which I couldn't figure out.

And here is,

```
<b-card img-src="../assets/image.jpg" img-alt="Image" img-top tag="article" style="max-width: 20rem;">
```

Comment: It seems like the problem might be the relative path to your image. This is possibly related to how your assets are being compiled/what build system you are using. Could you add some more details about your environment and how you are running Vue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include image in BootstrapVue carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456815/how-do-i-include-image-in-bootstrapvue-carousel)

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to import the image to your vue-component:

#### script

```
import image from "@/assets/your_img.jpg";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image
    }
  },
```

#### template

```
<b-card :img-src="image">
```

---

I think its beacause webpack generates a hash on the image path, eg. `"/img/my_image.b1793a36.jpg"`. I guess thats why your first approach doesn't work. If you import the image, webpack will add a hash automaticlly and the path will reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a broken image icon on your page?
-> wrong relative path to the image

If there is no broken image icon try to set a with/height and separate it from the b-card component into a normal img-tag inside the template environment in your component